# How can I get a number from html using c# htmlagility?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Basically I have this number in the html which is:

```
<span class="Account">(875)</span>
```

The xpath is

```
//*[@id="content-wrapper"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]
```

When I run my code I get nothing back.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='content - wrapper']/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]");

Console.WriteLine(node);
```

Like I said, I get a null back

Comment: The html code is <span class="Account">(875)</span> the website cut it off

Comment: The question is then whether your xpath expression is correct, which cannot be answered without seeing the actual HTML